# Google appengine pipelines - define the queue to use

Tags: google-app-engine

I'd like to be able to set which queue to use within a pipeline, so that I can use custom settings for that pipeline in queue.yaml.  The only way I can see to do this is to do so when the stage is started, via:

```
first_stage = ingest.CustomPipelineA(some_data)
first_stage.start(queue_name=foo)
```

However, I have nested and pre-requisite pipelines, such as:

```
with pipeline.InOrder():
    yield CustomPipelineA(some_shared_data)
    future_b = yield CustomPipelineB(some_shared_data)
    with pipeline.After(future_b):
        future_c = yield CustomPipelineC(some_shared_data, future_b)
        with pipeline.After(future_c):
            future_d = yield CustomPipelineD(some_shared_data, future_c)
```

It would be nice if I could set the queue name on the constructor, but it's not possible based on the pipeline docs:  https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/wiki/GettingStarted#Execution_ordering.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible in Python (but not in Java). Here's an example from the [same webpage as you linked to](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/wiki/GettingStarted#Achieving_parallelism) :

```
stage = MySearchEnginePipeline(15)
stage.start(queue_name='pipelinequeue')
```

Comment: Thanks David.  I believe start immediately returns and executes the next statement, whereas I need to yield and execute in a particular order.  Do you think this would work?


`with pipeline.InOrder():`
     `custom_a = CustomPipelineA(some_shared_data)`
     `future_b = yield custom_a.start(queue_name="pipelinequeue")`

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've figured this out for Execution Ordering, within the run statement, you can:

```
self._context.queue_name = "my-custom-queue-name"
```